# How do I find where 'data-price_excl_tax' is located to return value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The qty for a table appears to be held in 'data-price_excl_tax' with either no number, _2,_3,_4,_5,_6 or _12 after it. I cannot find where it is in the JS or html to be able to return the corresponding qty, which is with 1,2,3,4,5,6+,6-11, or 12+. I thought about doing an if statement that replaces it with it's corresponding number, but 6, if there's a 12 after it in the table is 6-11, whereas if 6 ends the table it is 6+. Not sure if that makes sense, but below is my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import requests
import json
import re
import numpy as np
import csv

urls = ["https://filterbuy.com/brand/air-demon-air-filters/air-demon-20x25-filters/",
"https://filterbuy.com/brand/air-demon-air-filters/air-demon-16x25-filters/",
"https://filterbuy.com/brand/air-demon-air-filters/air-demon-20x20-filters/",
"https://filterbuy.com/brand/air-demon-air-filters/air-demon-16x20-filters/"]
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    mervs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find_all('strong')
    product = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find("h1", class_="text-center")
    product_name = product.text
    qty="something in (data-price_excl_tax)"
    json_schema = soup.find_all('script', attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'})[1]
    json_file = json.loads(json_schema.get_text())
    the_dict = json_file
    n = the_dict['@graph'][0]
    descriptions = n['description']
    d = the_dict['@graph'][0]['aggregateRating']
    ratingValue = d['ratingValue']
    reviewCount = d['reviewCount']

    for i, cart in enumerate(BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find_all('form', class_='cart')):
        for tax in cart.attrs:
            if 'data-price' in tax:
                print(product_name.replace("\n", "").replace("('", "").strip(), mervs[i].get_text(), [tax], cart[tax], ratingValue, reviewCount)
                #header = ['merv', 'price', 'json_file']
                data = [product_name.replace("\n", "").replace("('", "").strip(), mervs[i].get_text(), cart[tax],ratingValue,reviewCount]
                with open('products.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter =',')
                    #writer.writerow(header)
                    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Prices table is generated dynamically with JS, they do not exists in html page as seen by requests. Your options would be to build an if/else logic based on numbers appearing in attrs (for instance, if there is no `price_excl_tax_12`, then discount applies to 6+, otherwise to 6-11, likewise if there's no _5 then you have a discounted price per filter for 4-5 items, and build this logic for any possible range of discount/items from that website. A second option would be to use selenium and get the data from `#price-table_wrap`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into the second route, never used selenium before.